# What did the Centurion mishear Pilate's statements as?

Tags: monty-python, life-of-brian

In the 1979 movie **Monty Python's Life of Brian**, there's scene where Brian (the protagonist) is captured by the Roman soldiers and brought to Pilate. Pilate seems to have rhotacism (a speech impediment that is defined by the lack of ability, or difficulty in, pronouncing the sound R). The segment I am talking about begins around 0:30 of this YouTube clip.

> **Pilate**:    Now, what is your name, Jew?
> **Brian**:     Brian.
> **Pilate**:    Bwian, eh?
> **Brian**:     No, *Brian*.  (the Centurion cuffs him.)
> **Pilate**:    (sniggers) The little wascal has thpiwit.
> **Centurion**: (confused) Has what, sir?
> **Pilate**:    *THPIWIT*.
> **Centurion**: Yes, he did, sir.
> **Pilate**:    No, no, thpiwit...bwavado...a touch of dewwing-do.
> **Centurion**: Ah. About eleven, sir.

Here, what were the *apparent questions* that Centurion answers with **"Yes, he did, sir."** and **"Ah. About eleven, sir."**?

Comment: I'm not sure the Centurion necessarily understood _anything_. It may well be that he couldn't make head nor tails out of Pilate's words, and just "winged it" and answered question that he guessed Pilate _might_ be asking.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck that's the point of the question here. What question might he have been answering. Sandun has asked us to enter an episode of Jeopardy with the Centurion.

Comment: I don't have anything official to go on, but isn't this a toilet joke? THPIWIT -> Sh*t and dewwing-do -> do-do. The centurion is answering with the last time the prisoner went to the loo.

Comment: @Jontia I don't think there's any connection between what Pilates says to the answer. Answering with the time is a common joke when the question is misheard, normally used by those hard of hearing. The joke here is flipping it so the fault is by the speaker not the listener and making it a touch more absurd/Python-esque.

Comment: _Non sequitur_ is a common joke in Python. _Non sequitur_ and repetition.. are two common jokes in Python...

Comment: Non sequitur, repetition & adding new postulates… **amongst** the common jokes in Monty Python ...

Comment: Mishearing a question as a request for the time seems to be a fairly common gag — at least, I'm fairly sure I've heard it many times — though I'm not sure whether they all refer back to some original instance, or it's just that asking for the time is fairly common and so one of the more likely guesses.

Answer (score 13):

There are no 'apparent questions' The joke is simply that the Centurion has no idea what Pilate has said so he gives a random answer that he hopes will do. He has already questioned Pilate once and doesn't want to do it again as that would draw attention to his speech impediment.

Answer (score -1):

Spiwit (spirit) - spew it or maybe spilled it. Either he has thrown up or "spilled the beans", as in, answered all their questions.

Dewing do (daring do- courage) - Doing doo, taking a crap, went to the loo.

That's how I understood the scene.

Comment: He's saying "spirit" and "derring-do" with a lisp that makes him incomprehensible to the centurion. I don't think there's any wordplay here.